# Calling server method opening file from AJAX

Tags: jquery, asp.net

I am calling a server webmethod which opens a byte array in notepad.

```
HttpContext.Current.Response.OutputStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
HttpContext.Current.Response.Flush();
HttpContext.Current.Response.End();
```

when I call that method from ajax code is getting executed but it's not openning
I am calling through regular ajax post method.when I call throgh server submit
It's working.

Comment: Using dev tools (network activity), what's in the response of your AJAX call?

Comment: Yes.It's static void.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because you can't download a file through AJAX... The best alternative for this is, I guess, instead of doing the request through AJAX, to insert an invisible iFrame in the page with its source set to the "file download" script you're calling.

This solution is javascript triggered and will open the file download dialog you're expecting.

Comment: I'm not sure to understand the question... but SRC should indeed point to the address you're requesting in your AJAX call. That will actually do the exact same thing (a `GET` request) as typing the URL directly in the address bar.